# using a button to make a user control visible in WPF using MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a grid in WPF that contains a button which should make a user control visible. How do I make this possible using MVVM pattern and /or code behind?

Comment: All this changes, are UI related, do it on your view code, don't touch viewmodels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following a full example on how you can achieve this in MVVM  with an illustration of ICommand interface.
your main should look like this

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Height="350"
    Width="525"
    xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3">
  <Grid>
    <my:UserControl1  Background="Aqua"
                  Visibility="{Binding ChangeControlVisibility,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  Margin="111,66,0,0"
                  x:Name="userControl11"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  Height="156"
                  Width="195" />
    <Button Content="Button"
        Height="36"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Margin="36,18,0,0"
        Name="button1"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Width="53"
        Command="{Binding  MyButtonClickCommand}" />
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.cs**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApplication3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new MyViewModel(); 
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
    public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MyViewModel()
        {
           _myCommand = new MyCommand(FuncToCall,FuncToEvaluate);
        }

        private ICommand _myCommand;

        public ICommand MyButtonClickCommand
        {
            get { return _myCommand; }
            set { _myCommand = value; }
        }

        private void FuncToCall(object context)
        {
            //this is called when the button is clicked
            //for example
            if (this.ChangeControlVisibility== Visibility.Collapsed)
            {
              this.ChangeControlVisibility = Visibility.Visible;   
            }
            else
            {
              this.ChangeControlVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;  
            }                
        }

        private bool FuncToEvaluate(object context)
        {            
            return true;
        }

        private Visibility _visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        public Visibility ChangeControlVisibility
        {
            get { return _visibility; }
            set {
                 _visibility = value;
                 this.OnPropertyChanged("ChangeControlVisibility");
            }    
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

**Command:**

```
    class MyCommand : ICommand
    {
        public delegate void ICommandOnExecute(object parameter);
        public delegate bool ICommandOnCanExecute(object parameter);
        private ICommandOnExecute _execute;
        private ICommandOnCanExecute _canExecute;

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _canExecute.Invoke(parameter);
        }

        public MyCommand(ICommandOnExecute onExecuteMethod, ICommandOnCanExecute onCanExecuteMethod)
        {
        _execute = onExecuteMethod;
        _canExecute = onCanExecuteMethod;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _execute.Invoke(parameter);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks good. You can use `Action<>` and `Func<>` instead of the delegates if you want to save some typing.

Comment: that's true but  the user maybe newbie after all Action<> and Func<> are  delegates

Answer (score 3):

In your view model you want a bool property for the visibility of the user control. We'll call it IsUserControlVisible. Now you'll need a command in your view model that will set the IsUserControlVisible property to true. We'll call this ShowUserControlCommand.

In XAML you would bind the visibility of the User Control to IsUserControlVisible. In WPF there is a BooleanToVisibilityConverter, so we don't have to create our own converter. Your XAML would look something like this.

```
<Window
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

  <Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
  </Window.Resources>

  <Grid> 
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="50" />
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button Command="{Binding ShowUserControlCommand}">Show</Button>
    <UserControl Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{Binding IsUserControlVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Generally speaking you have a boolean flag in your viewmodel that is bound to the user controls `Visibility` using an appropriate converter. You have a command in your viewmodel that is bound to the button's `Command` property. The Execute method of the command toggles the boolean flag.

Edit:

If you only need the button to make something visible on form, consider the [Expander control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.controls.expander%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that already does this out of the box.

```
<Expander>
   <YourUserControl/>
</Expander>
```

Comment: he does  not need to use converter at all here

Comment: @K.B as Visibility is not of type System.Boolean, he may want to.